# PayPal V1 to V2

Tags: curl, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

The old command of curl was:
[https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/{payment_id}/execute](https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/%7Bpayment_id%7D/execute)

I can't find a comparable query in the V2 version of the PayPal API, but I need exactly the same method. How do I manage to execute a transaction, the customer does not order anything from us but loads his credit with it. So no checkout Cart or this kind of stuff.

Tried to find Something similar, but no Resolution for now.

Answer (score 0):

For checkout, the equivalent of v1/payments/.../execute is v2/checkout/orders/.../capture

To securely process a card via web, a v2/checkout/orders backend can be used with either a [Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/) (expanding inline form) or an [Advanced](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/) (customized fields) integration.

If your question is about processing a card that is first stored or travels through your own server (and is later sent to PayPal via API), the payment card industry requires [PCI SAQ-D compliance](https://listings.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/SAQ_D_v3_Merchant.pdf) (PDF) for such integrations that **don't** post the card number directly to the payment processor via secure web. There is a `payment_source.card` parameter in the v2/checkout/orders API for such an integration. Not recommended.

If your question is about storing a tokenized card for later use (card on file), US business accounts can integrate the [vault API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/save-payment-methods/purchase-later/cards/). Other countries should first contact PayPal's general business support about being approved for reference transactions/billing agreements in the live environment --and once approved for that live account feature PayPal can guide you on which API to integrate. Alternatively, the Braintree gateway integration is available in [many major countries](https://www.braintreepayments.com/country-selection) and its APIs obviously have tokenization support.